# UINavigationController - two left buttons plus back button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

In my view I need to have two left buttons on my nav bar. A custom button and also the standard back button (created by the nav controller) on the left.

However I need to have the back button the normal standard back button arrow and have a method which is called when tapping it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember reading somewhere in the Human Interface Guidelines that Apple specifically discourages this.  Unless you are willing to risk app rejection and possibly confusing your users, I'd recommend you dig into the HIG and find out if you can do this or not.

If you need to have it, you will have to make your own custom implementation, as the nav bar doesn't support what your asking.  You will need to hide the back button, then place your own custom back buttons on the bar, likely created from a sub-class of UIView.

If you don't need them both to be back buttons, then you might get away with getting the frame of the back button, and placing another button of your own to the right of it.

Comment: The alert will simply have a message such as 'Are you sure...etc', because of the nature of the use of the view. I have tried adding a custom view as the left button item, a toolbar with two button items, but I can't get the desired effect. Also it results in an oddly large indentation in tot he nab bar and doesn't sit in the norma position.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you want exactly.  Alert?  If you want two buttons, I'd leave the nav bar the way it is, then add another button over top of the view controller's view itself, then position it as needed.  Don't add it to the nav bar if it won't accept it (although I haven't tried doing so, I don't know why it wouldn't work).  Maybe you could post a sketch of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Ok, let me start from scratch, ignore the alert. I want to have my nab bar with two left buttons. So I have the standard auto created back button (I make no changes to that), then I want next to that (no on the far right side but on the next next to the back button) my UIBarButtonItem that I make. Any ideas how I could? I have seen solutions by ma,ing a custom view with a toolbar but that removes the auto created back button completely and you have to make one yourself.

Comment: Create a UIButton, then add it to the UINavigationBar.view and adjust it's frame  to where you want it to sit.  You may have to get a reference to the navigation bar back button and adjust the added buttons frame to make it sit just to the right of it.